# split argument and create a new variables

Tags: bash, variable, arguments

My argument look like: `My_Submit.sh May5_2014` and I want to create
a new variable inspired from the argument, this variable should look
like `May14_5`.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
zmodload zsh/langinfo
date=${1?date not specified}

if
  [[ $date = (#b)(${(vj[|])~langinfo[(I)ABMON_<1-12>]})(<1-31>)_20([0-9][0-9]) ]]
then
  newdate=$match[1]$match[3]_$match[2]
else
  print -ru2 -- $date is not in the right format
  exit 1
fi

print -r New date is $newdate.
```

That's retrieving the list of abbreviations from locale data via the `zsh/langinfo` module. If the abbreviations must be the English ones regardless of the user's locale, you can just change `${(vj[|])~langinfo[(I)ABMON_<1-12>]}` to `Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string in the single argument is on the format `XXXY_ZZNN`, where `XXX` is an arbitrary string without digits and `Y` is some whole number, and where `Z`, and `N` are single characters.  You want to transform `XXXY_ZZNN` into `XXXNN_Y`, dropping `ZZ` from the string and swapping `Y` and `NN` around the underscore.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 =~ ^([^[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)_..(..)$ ]]; then
    printf -v variable '%s%s_%s' \
        "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
else
    echo 'Argument missing or on the wrong format' >&2
    exit 1
fi

printf 'Variable = "%s"\n' "$variable"
```

This uses a regular expression match is the `bash` shell to identify the various parts of the input string.  If the expression matches, the various parts of the matching string are rearranged to form the new value.  This value is assigned to the variable called `variable` (which is outputted at the end).

Testing it:

```
$ ./script May5_2014
Variable = "May14_5"
$ ./script Bumblebee10_1973
Variable = "Bumblebee73_10"
$ ./script Bumblebee10_173
Argument missing or on the wrong format
$ ./script Bumblebee10_ABCD
Variable = "BumblebeeCD_10"
```

Comment: i recommend this script for everyone have the same issue